# Авторизация Вконтакте OAuth.

Tags: oauth, android, вконтакте

Всем Бодрого дня!
Реализовал **авторизацию** и отправку **сообщения на стену Вконтакте** следующим образом:

```
public class VkAuthWebAct extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
WebView wv;
String access_token
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vk_auth_web);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.test)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back)).setOnClickListener(this);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new VKWebViewClient());
    wv.loadUrl("http://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/authorize?" +
            "client_id=123456&" +
            "scope=wall,notify,docs&" +
            "redirect_uri=http://api.vkontakte.ru/blank.html&" +
            "display=wap&" +
            "response_type=token");       
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.test:
        if (wv.getUrl().substring(35, 47).equals("access_token")){
            writeOnTheWall();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "access_denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    break;
    case R.id.btn_back:
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("acc_token", access_token);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
        finish();
    break;
    }
}

void writeOnTheWall(){
    access_token=wv.getUrl().split("#")[1].split("&")[0].split("=")[1];                     
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request=new HttpPost("https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/wall.post?");
        List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", "сообщенние с пробелами"));
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("friends_only", "1"));
        qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", access_token));
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(qparams, HTTP.UTF_8));
        httpClient.execute(request);
        request.abort();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Код то рабочий, но как с ним "работать" )) т.е. мне не нравится, что я тут наваял :)

1. Почему каждый раз при запуске этого `Activity` у меня запрашивается **Разрешение** на "Получение доступа ВКонтакте"? 
   Ведь в документации написано: "Если срок использования ключа истек, то необходимо повторно провести все описанные выше шаги, но в этом случае пользователю уже **не** придется дважды разрешать доступ." У меня же ещё и срок не истёк, а уже надо разрешение. 
   Может `access_token` получается как-то иначе? Или надо донастроить `WebView`?
2. Как можно реализовать авторизацию без использования `WebView`, а через `EditBox`'ы? Ведь вариант ждать когда НА ЭКРАНЕ появится `token` и потом его брать - плохой вариант.
3. Как организовать **выход**, чтобы можно было зайти под другой учётной записью?

Comment: Ответ есть на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/129648/)

Comment: На хабре нет ответа. Вопрос остается открытым - почему каждый раз при авторизации запрашивается разрешение? При чем методом научного тыка выяснилось, что с правами audio,friends,status разрешение спрашивается только один раз, а потом происходит сразу выдача токена, а если добавить еще, к примеру, photos, тогда будет каждый раз при авторизации запрашивать разрешение.
WTF? :)